# How to convert list of child type to list of parent type

Tags: generics, collections, kotlin

I imagine there is a pretty way of doing this, but I just cannot see it.
Say I have the class `class Bull: Dog`. If I have `Set<Bull> bulls` and a function `fun doSomeCool(vararg input:Dog)`, what should I do with `bulls` so that I can pass it to `doSomeCool`? For example, the following doesn't work:

```
doSomeCool(*bulls.toTypedArray())
```

*UPDATE*

I am so sorry I asked the question backwards. Slight but important changes:

I have classes:

```
class Dog(val name:String)//there are actually more properties

class Bull(name:String):Dog(name){  
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Int = 0//not used in equals function
}
```

Then I have the set

```
val dogs:HashSet<Dog>=...
```

then I need to pass dogs to the following method

```
fun insert(vararg bull:Bull){...}//insert into a DB of Bulls
```

So really I need to somehow magically downcast from Dog to Bull -- since they are really the same type except for the auto-generated primary key, which by the way is not used in equals (I don't even override equals, Bull uses the implementation of Dog). Is there an easy way to do this without having to create a news instance of each element in dogs?

Comment: So far as I can tell, what you have would compile (see e.g. https://ideone.com/qBhMKN).

Comment: Do you totally sure that all dogs in the hashset are instances of Bull? If it contains instances of an other child of dog class, desirable casting would be failed!